# Can't upgrade my Ubuntu server, it gets stuck on openjdk-6-jre-headless

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, java

I am using Ubuntu Server.

When I do:

apt-get upgrade

it gets stuck on:

Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1) ...

Why? And what can I do to stop it?

I tried removing it with apt-get... I get this error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So then I tried this:

```
dpkg --purge openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

I got this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of openjdk-6-jre-headless:
 openjdk-6-jre-lib depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b17).
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is to be removed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless which provides java6-runtime-headless is to be removed.
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is to be removed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless which provides java6-runtime-headless is to be removed.
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre-headless (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

The thing is I think my DB is using it... Not sure... I am using Cassandra with Thrift...

Yes, it's getting a bit more complex...

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-6-jre:
 openjdk-6-jre depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libaccess-bridge-java:
 libaccess-bridge-java depends on default-jre | openjdk-6-jre | sun-java6-jre; however:
  Package default-jre is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre is not configured yet.
  Package sun-java6-jre is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libaccess-bridge-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-6-jre-cacao:
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing icedtea-6-jre-cacao (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libaccess-bridge-java-jni:
 libaccess-bridge-java-jni depends on libaccess-bridge-java (>= 1.26.2-5); however:
  Package libaccess-bridge-java is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libaccess-bridge-java-jni (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre
 libaccess-bridge-java
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao
 libaccess-bridge-java-jni
```

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had little upgrade problems like this before.

two possibilities, try:

```
apt-get update
```

then

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Failing that, try

```
apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

Then

```
apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

Comment: Even when I try to remove ecj (javac) it gets stuck on: Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1) ...

Comment: The server actually crashes. I have to reboot every time... And some times multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is a Java application and depending on which version you are running it requires different Java packages. In the past it has required openjdk but I believe the newer version will accept sunJDK. You have to have one of them for it to work.

Comment: The problem is not at that level. The problem was with Amazon AWS EC2 package manager. I tried installing Javac on RackSpace and I did not have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -C` will audit your system for misconfigured or non-functioning packages, then recommend a solution.

You should try manually removing the top of the dependency tree, too: have you tried to remove `ca-certificates-java`? If that remove fails, you can remove its requirer, and so on and so forth.

As a last resort:
If you run `dpkg` with the `--force-depends` flag, all dependency errors automagically turn into warnings. Thereby allowing you to hose your system, of course; use with caution. Certainly include the `--dry-run` option first to check that what's being done is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Lowman for your input. But I have since then switch to RackSpace. It seems that there was a problem with Amazon Package manager and that was why I couldn't install Javac properly. But still thank you for your tips.